# How to change src of a frame from another page using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here i want to change the src property of my frame which has id="bodyFrame" and that is on a seperate html docement.
How can I refer it through javascript.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function loadpage()
            {
                var s=document.getElementById('selection');
                //alert(s.value);
                var k=document.getElementById('bodyFrame');
                alert(k);

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Select the page to visit :
        <select id="selection" onchange="loadpage()">
            <option value="Home">Home</option>
            <option value="Staff">Staff</option>
            <option value="Table">Table</option>
            <option value="Video">Video</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here I am looking for a solution instead of `document.getElementById('bodyFrame');`

Comment: `k.src  = 'Your desired page url'` ?

Comment: k is null. because that is not in this page.

Comment: You cannot use `iframe` of other page provided its not child / parent of current page.

Comment: it is not an iframe. It is a frameset.

Comment: You should not use `frames` in your website. Also, show relevant markup how you are using frames.

Answer (score 0):

Try `parent` or `opener`. These will give you the window you want, depending on your scenario. Anyway, you can just write `debugger;` and the code will stop in that line (if you've enabled client side debugging) so you can inspect what do the values of `parent` and `opener` hold.

Comment: Come on... I've given you exactly what you need... do some experiment with the debugger - the goal in Stack Overflow is not to program things for people but to help them do the job.